# Xamarin 3.3.0 forms error: Type ToolbarItem not found in xmlns

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding [AddPhoto]}" Command="{Binding AddNewPhotoCommand}" Order="Primary" x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Icon="{OnPlatform iOS='photo.png', UWP='Assets/photo.png'}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

and I got:

> Type ToolbarItem not found in xmlns
>   http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

If I remove entire part after `x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"` mean

```
 <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding [AddPhoto]}" Command="{Binding AddNewPhotoCommand}" Order="Primary"/>
```

then is fine, no error.

I upgraded project to Xamarin 3.3.0 and I changed from

```
<ToolbarItem Text="{Binding [AddPhoto]}" Command="{Binding AddNewPhotoCommand}" Order="Primary" >
      <ToolbarItem.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
          <On Platform="iOS" Value="photo.png"/>
          <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/photo.png"/>
        </OnPlatform>
      </ToolbarItem.Icon>
</ToolbarItem>
```

to

```
<ToolbarItem Text="{Binding [AddPhoto]}" Command="{Binding AddNewPhotoCommand}" Order="Primary" x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Icon="{OnPlatform iOS='photo.png', UWP='Assets/photo.png'}"/>
```

Why ?

I don't have typo or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check out](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/139493/is-onplatform-only-deprecated-for-code-and-not-xaml-the-documentation-says-to-utilize-switch-class) how it should be used:

```
<ContentPage Title="Browse">
        <ContentPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS">tab_feed.png</On>
                <On Platform="Android>tab_feedand.png</On>
                <On Platform="UWP>/Images/tab_feed.png</On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ContentPage.Icon>
    </ContentPage>
```

Will become:

```
<ContentPage Title="Browse" Icon="{x:OnPlatform iOS='tab_afeed.png', Android='tab_feedand.png', UWP='/Images/tab_feed.png' />
```

No need to specify x:TypeArguments.

[x:typeArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-typearguments-directive) passes constraining type arguments of a generic to the constructor of the generic type. So it's related to [OnPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.onplatform?view=xamarin-forms) method, but you specify it for ToolbarItem.

Comment: If I specify `x:TypeArguments` then error is back ... don't know why

Comment: What about: `<Style TargetType="Label">    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,0,0,0" Android="0,0,0,0" UWP="0,0,0,0"/>   </Style>` ? I got that UWP is not bindable or not good property or value mismatch.

Comment: @SnakeEyes See new xaml syntax sample https://montemagno.com/important-onplatform-changes-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @SnakeEyes, Should be something like this, I will check it tomorrow <ContentPage Padding='{OnPlatform Android="10,5,10,0", iOS="10,20,10,0"}'>

Comment: If you can help me tomorrow on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931101/xamarin-3-3-0-forms-error-a-lot-of-issues-when-migrate-from-xamarin-2-5-to-3-3