# Xamarin 3.3.0 forms error: a lot of issues when migrate from Xamarin 2.5 to 3.3.0

Tags: c#, xamarin

**Isse one:**

I changed old code (to support xamarin 3.0) from:

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="CrossPlatformStackOrientation" x:TypeArguments="StackOrientation">
          <On Platform="iOS" Value="Vertical"/>
          <On Platform="UWP" Value="Horizontal"/>
</OnPlatform>
```

to

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="CrossPlatformStackOrientation" x:TypeArguments="StackOrientation" iOS="Vertical" UWP="Horizontal" />
```

I met the following error:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'UWP', or
>   mismatching type between value and property.

If I remove `x:TypeArguments`, no error occur but on runtime, I got

> Cannot determine property to provide the value for

**Issue two:**

I get error

> Expected '}'

for

```
<Label Text="{Binding Description.CreationDateTime,Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{0:dd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss}'}"
                     Style="{StaticResource MyResourceText}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,3,5,0"/>
```

**Issue three:**

for

```
<GridLength x:Key="TileSeparatorHeight">0</GridLength>
```

I got:

> The type 'GridLength' does not support direct content.

It happens for Thickness too:

```
<Thickness x:Key="TileStartDatePadding">0,0,0,0</Thickness>
```

How to solve them ?

Comment: Device.OnPlatform is obsolete and has been replaced by Device.RuntimePlatform

Comment: Better to assign this issue here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround for Issue 1,3:**

Define class in your app:

```
public class XamlConsts
{
    public readonly Thickness TileStartDatePadding = new Thickness(0);
    public readonly GridLength TileSeparatorHeight = new GridLength(0);
    public StackOrientation CrossPlatformStackOrientation
    {
        get
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.UWP:
                    return StackOrientation.Horizontal;
                case Device.iOS:
                    return StackOrientation.Vertical;
                default: return StackOrientation.Horizontal;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Add it to resources:

```
<local:XamlConsts x:Key="XamlConsts"></local:XamlConsts>
```

Use it:

```
<StackLayout Padding="{Binding Source={StaticResource XamlConsts},Path=TileStartDatePadding}"  Orientation="{Binding Source={StaticResource XamlConsts},Path=CrossPlatformStackOrientation}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={StaticResource XamlConsts},Path=TileSeparatorHeight}"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

**Issue one**

This approach is no longer valid since OnPlatform infer types from properties in which it is used, when you declare it in resources it cannot determine type.

You can use alternative approach:
1. Define Converter:

```
public class OrientationConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.UWP:
                    return StackOrientation.Horizontal;
                case Device.iOS:
                    return StackOrientation.Vertical;
                default: return StackOrientation.Horizontal;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

How to use this converter:

```
<local:OrientationConverter x:Key="CrossPlatformStackOrientationConverter"/>
<x:Int32 x:Key="intConst">1</x:Int32>
       </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout Orientation="{Binding Source={StaticResource intConst}, Converter={StaticResource CrossPlatformStackOrientationConverter}}">
```

Where "1" is just any int constant and does not have any sense.

**Issue two**

This is a bug.

Workaround:

Define constant in Resources:

```
<x:String x:Key="dateFormat">{0:dd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss}</x:String>
```

Use it:

```
Text="{Binding Description.CreationDateTime,Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource dateFormat}}"
```

**Issue three**

Seems like xamarin bug. You can create converter as I described in Issue one, but it should work out of the box.

Comment: I don't know for `GridLength` and `Thickness`, how to declare converter for those

Comment: `Binding 1` give me: `Invalid property path syntax` error

Comment: @SnakeEyes I added better approach at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thanks... Have you met the error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine property to provide the value for.` ? It happens at runtime and I don't see the source of failure

Comment: @SnakeEyes I use code with switch(Device.RuntimePlatform). See how it's done for CrossPlatformStackOrientation.

Comment: It happens when you use OnPlatform outside of the control properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182492/discussion-between-snake-eyes-and-access-denied).